# How do I make permanent name tags in Minecraft? (I meant to make name tags stay when placed/broken block)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I make permanent name tags in Minecraft? (I meant to make name tags stay when placed/broken block) Because every time I place or break a block, the name tag isn't on anymore... Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Only containers and command blocks remember their name when placed, the former displaying it at the top of their UIs and the latter displaying it when executing /say.